# Why is spawn_link necessary in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

I understand that if you do spawn followed by link, the process may have died in the mean time. Why is that a problem? Can't link see that you're trying to link to a process that has already died? In that case couldn't it just behave as though the remote process died immediately after link was called?

I think it would be nice if you could do spawn and link separately, and not have to do them together in one atomic function, because a) that would make the language more orthogonal (spawn_link heavily overlaps with spawn and link) b) if I have a start function that's basically just a wrapper around spawn, I ALSO need to supply start_link. So the non-orthogonality is viral. Yuck!

Comment: You're missing the distinction between links and monitors, and then proceeding to reinvent `spawn_link` in theory. This is good. Once you realize the utility of `spawn`, `link`, `monitor`, `spawn_link` and `spawn_monitor` it will make deeper sense to you; you've already reasoned through half of it above, just starting from incorrect assumptions.

Comment: Yes, I realize that I am missing something. That's why I asked this question...

Comment: Originally we didn't have `spawn_link` and everything worked fine. Then we slightly changed when spawned processes were run in relation to the spawner and suddenly we missed cases where there should have been a signal. It took some thinking to work out what was going wrong. N.B. both ways were right but different, a typical problem if you try and "assume" in which order things will run without synchronisation.

Answer (score 8):

Remember that links are bidirectional, so consider the case where process A spawns process B but then dies before being able to link to B. In this case, B has no idea that it is not linked to A, and it does not die when A dies.

With `spawn_link` this scenario can't happen because the spawn and link either occur together atomically, or they both fail.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. I think the problem that you mention can be solved without spawn_link, albeit in an ugly way: B's function takes Parent, and A passes self(). Then, B also calls link in case A did not call link in time. If A does not intend to link, it can pass no_link instead of self(). Of course, this adds more responsibility/boiler plate/error-prone code to B, which does suck.

Comment: You also have to add code to A so it either kills itself (as per link rules) or catches the failure of B to start properly in some other way (as if `spawn_link` had failed entirely). That's a *lot* of boilerplate, hence this abstraction being built into the language in a deeper way by simply guaranteeing that it is an atomic procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason, which cannot be emulated:

If a process is trapping exit signals, then if first spawns and then tries to link to a process that dies immediately, the failed link will result in a `{'EXIT',..., noproc}` exit signal.

If `spawn_link` is used, however, the exit signal will always carry the real exit reason.