# Erlang: spawning process with monitor

Tags: erlang, monitoring, spawn

I'm working through Joe Armstrong's [Programming Erlang 2nd E](https://pragprog.com/book/jaerlang2/programming-erlang). The book has exercises at the end of each chapter. Chapter 13, exercise 1 says:

> Write a function `my_spawn(Mod, Func, Args)` that behaves like `spawn(Mod, Func, Args)` but with one difference. If the spawned process dies, a message should be printed saying why the process died and how long the process lived for before it died.

Here's a solution that has a race condition:

```erlang
my_spawn(Mod, Func, Args) ->
    Pid = spawn(Mod, Func, Args),
    spawn(fun() ->
                  Ref = monitor(process, Pid),
                  T1 = erlang:monotonic_time(millisecond),
                  receive
                      {'DOWN', Ref, process, Pid, Why} ->
                          io:format("~p died because of ~p~n", [Pid, Why]),
                          io:format("~p lived for ~p ms~n", [Pid, erlang:monotonic_time(millisecond) - T1])
                  end
          end),
    Pid.
```

Spawning the process and creating the monitor is *not* an atomic step, so if the process dies after spawning but before the monitor is created, we won't get the error message.

Here's an attempt without the race condition:

```erlang
my_spawn_atomic(Mod, Func, Args) ->
    spawn(fun() ->
                  {Pid, Ref} = spawn_monitor(Mod, Func, Args),
                  T1 = erlang:monotonic_time(millisecond),
                  receive {'DOWN', Ref, process, Pid, Why} ->
                          io:format("~p died because of ~p~n", [Pid, Why]),
                          io:format("~p lived for ~p ms~n", [Pid, erlang:monotonic_time(millisecond) - T1])
                  end
          end).
```

But the PID this returns is that of the monitoring process, not the `Func` process. And given that `spawn` always returns the PID of the process it creates, there doesn't seem to be a way to return `Pid` without resorting to a side effect.

What's the idiomatic way to do implement the atomic spawning?

Comment: You should have a look at [`spawn_link`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#spawn_link-1). See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/28531101/409228 .

Comment: How does `spawn_link` help? I'm already using `spawn_monitor`.

Comment: As already was mentioned before, atomic spawning already implement as  [spawn_link/1](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#spawn_link-1). Btw, maybe you also found interesting chapter [Errors and Processes](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/errors-and-processes) from LYSE.

Comment: why do you wrap everything in spawn? just get rid of the spawn and it will work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send Pid from monitoring process as a message:

```
my_spawn_atomic(Mod, Func, Args) ->
    Parent = self(),
    MPid = spawn(fun() ->
                  {Pid, Ref} = spawn_monitor(Mod, Func, Args),
                  Parent ! {spawned, self(), Pid},
                  T1 = erlang:monotonic_time(millisecond),
                  receive {'DOWN', Ref, process, Pid, Why} ->
                          io:format("~p died because of ~p~n", [Pid, Why]),
                          io:format("~p lived for ~p ms~n", [Pid, erlang:monotonic_time(millisecond) - T1])
                  end
          end),
    receive
        {spawned, MPid, Pid} -> Pid
    after 1000 -> error % 1s should be way enough for spawning monitoring process
    end.
```

Another option is to wrap the function in a fun with *an init phase*:

```
my_spawn(Mod, Func, Args) ->
    Pid = spawn(fun() ->
            receive run -> apply(Mod, Func, Args)
            after 1000 -> exit(init_timeout)
            end
        end),
    spawn(fun() ->
                  Ref = monitor(process, Pid),
                  T1 = erlang:monotonic_time(millisecond),
                  Pid ! run,
                  receive
                      {'DOWN', Ref, process, Pid, Why} ->
                          io:format("~p died because of ~p~n", [Pid, Why]),
                          io:format("~p lived for ~p ms~n", [Pid, erlang:monotonic_time(millisecond) - T1])
                  end
          end),
    Pid.
```

Comment: Hmm...this seems like a common enough pattern that I'd have thought there'd be an easier way to do this, but both of your solutions are valid. Perhaps the patterns are captured as part of some built-in behavior...

Comment: @TianxiangXiong: No, it is not. There is very little usage in such detached monitor. There is a common pattern you want your process to die with subprocess and vice versa and it is where you use `spawn_link` and there is a common pattern you want to monitor other process and there is not spawned detached monitor so you use `spawn_monitor` and there is OTP with workers and supervisor tree. There is very little practical use for your pattern except for educational one.

Answer (score 0):

http://marcelog.github.io/articles/erlang_link_vs_monitor_difference.html

The difference between spawn_link and spaw_monitor is well explained here.

```
-module(mon_test).
-export([my_spawn/3, die_in/1]).

my_spawn(Mod, Func, Args) ->
    spawn(my_spawn(mon_test, my_spawn, [self(), Mod, Func, Args]),
    receive
        Pid -> Pid
        after 1000 -> timeout
    end.

my_spawn(Parent, Mod, Func, Args) ->
    {Pid, Ref} = spawn_monitor(Mod, Func, Args),
    T1 = erlang:system_time(),
    Parent ! Pid,
    receive
       {'DOWN', Ref, _Any, Pid, Why} -> 
        io:format("~p died because of ~p, lived for ~p milliseconds~n", [Pid, Why, (erlang:system_time()-T1)/1000/1000])
    end.

die_in(Secs) ->
  receive 
    Reason -> exit(Reason)
    after Secs*1000 -> exit(timeout_reason)
end.


> mon_test:my_spawn(mon_test, die_in, [5]).
<0.155.0>
<0.155.0> died because of timeout_reason, lived for 5001.152 milliseconds
```